# How to access positional parameters from within a for loop

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, bash-scripting

My shell script contains a `for` loop. The script makes use of positional arguments via `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. However, trying to access these parameters from the `for` loop using something like this:

```
for i in "$@"; do 
echo "$1"
done
```

... selects the very first expanded value. For example, when provided with a list of files via a glob (`./script.sh *.mp4`), in every iteration of the `for` loop the value of `$1` will be the first file that the glob expands to.

The exact same seems to apply to doing:

```
for i in "$@"; do 
echo "$i"
done
```

Is it possible to use positional arguments within a `for` loop, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd snippet works just fine:

```bsh
# set some positional parameters
set -- foo bar baz

# iterate
for item in "$@"; do
  echo "=> $item"
done
```

result

```
=> foo
=> bar
=> baz
```

If you want to iterate over the *indices*, you need an arithmetic for loop, and indirect expansion:

```bsh
for ((i = 1; i <= $#; i++)); do
  echo "$i => ${!i}"
done
```

outputs

```
1 => foo
2 => bar
3 => baz
```

Ref: [3.2.5.1 Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs), [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Apologies, it appears not testing thoroughly enough means I misunderstood the problem. I've accepted this answer to this question and asked a restated, more defined version of the question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1649449/access-positional-parameters-out-of-order-in-a-for-loop).