# Access positional parameters out of order in a for loop

Tags: command-line, bash, script, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have a script which makes use of multiple (i.e. positional) arguments from the command line, and within it a `for` loop that iterates through these arguments:

```
for i in "$@"; do 
...
done
```

This means that the arguments are populated into `$i` one by one, in the order that they're specified on the command line.

This seems to mean that it's impossible to select an argument that is not currently populating  `$i`.

For example, in the following line in my script, I need to reference two different variables, which outside of a `for` loop would be `$1`, `$2` and `$1` respectively:

```
ffmpeg -i "$i" -i "$i" ... "${i%.*}.mp4"
```

The script is executed in the following format:

```
./script.sh image.jpg *.flac
```

...but as I understand things, this problem would apply even to scripts that don't work with globs.

Is it possible to access positional arguments from a `for` loop as needed, rather than simply in the order they are specified in?

Comment: Please show some sample filenames, and the resulting ffmpeg invocations you want to run. Does the `...` part involve any filenames?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a variable with the value of `$1` and then `shift 1`? You can also do array slicing on `$@`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701400/remove-first-element-from-in-bash

Comment: In bash you can select arguments out of order and in loops, by using indirect variable expansion, `${!i}`, that expands to the content of the parameter whose name is stored in the `i` variable. Or for example `${@:3}` for all arguments from the third to the end. See [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out in the end, although I don't consider this a perfect answer to the question because it doesn't satisfy the requirement of being able to reference the arguments from within the `for` loop.

In this sense I see this answer as more of a workaround, and I'm more than happy for someone else to come along and directly answer the question in a more comprehensive way. In any case, it's a workaround that works for my current script.

```
  img="$1"
  shift
  for i in "$@"; do
  ...
  ffmpeg -i "$img" -i "$i" ... "${i%.*}.mp4"
  ...
  done
```

As far as I can tell, this works by assigning the first argument to a variable `$img` outside of the `for` loop. Each instance of `$img` in the script is processed and then discarded by `shift` (which is the same as `shift 1`) before moving on to the next.

Once all $img arguments are removed from the arguments list, the `for` loop uses the `$@` to loop through the remaining arguments as normal.

The script can then be called with something like:

```
./script.sh customimage.png *.flac
```

Or for multiple instances of the `$img` variable:

```
./script.sh customimage.png custom-image2.jpg *.flac
```